# Dataproc, Dataprep and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm trying to create ML models dealing with big datasets. My question is more related to the preprocessing of these big datasets. In this sense, I'd like to know what are the differences between doing the preprocessing with Dataprep, Dataproc or Tensorflow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are 3 different things, you can't really compare them.

> Dataprep - data service for visually exploring, cleaning, and
>   preparing structured and unstructured data for analysis

In other words, if you have a large training data and you want to clean it up, visualize etc. google dataprep enables you to do that easily.

> Cloud Dataproc is a fast, easy-to-use, fully-managed cloud service for
>   running Apache Spark and Apache Hadoop clusters in a simpler, more
>   cost-efficient way.

Within the context of your question, after you cleanup your data and it is ready to feed into your ML algorithm, you can use Cloud Dataproc to distribute it across multiple nodes and process it much faster. In some machine learning algorithms the disk read speed might be a bottleneck so it could greatly improve your machine learning algorithms running time.

Finally Tensorflow:

> TensorFlow™ is an open source software library for numerical
>   computation using data flow graphs. Nodes in the graph represent
>   mathematical operations, while the graph edges represent the
>   multidimensional data arrays (tensors) communicated between them.

So after your data is ready to process; you can use Tensorflow to implement machine learning algorithms. Tensorflow is a python library so it is relatively easy to pick up. Tensorflow also enables to run your algorithms on GPU instead of CPU and (recently) also on Google Cloud TPUs(hardware made specifically for machine learning, even better performance than GPUs).

Answer (score 3):

In the context of preprocessing for Machine Learning, I would like to put a time to answer this question in details. So, please bear with me!

Google provides four different processing products. Since, preprocessing has different aspects and covers many different ML prerequisites, each of these platforms is more suitable for a particular preprocessing domain. Products are as follows:

**Google ML Engine/ Cloud AI**:  This product is based on Tensorflow. You can run your Machine Learning code in Tensorflow on the  ML Engine. For specific types of data like image, text or sequential,  tf.keras.preprocessing or tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing Libraries are available to make the appropriate input/tensor format of data for Tensorflow rapidly. 
You may also need to transform your data via  [tf.Transform](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/02/preprocessing-for-machine-learning-with.html) in a preprocessing step. tf.Transform, a library for TensorFlow, allows users to define preprocessing pipelines as part of a TensorFlow graph. tf.Transform ensures that no skew can arise during preprocessing.

**Cloud DataPrep**: Preprocessing sometimes is defined as data cleaning, data cleansing, data prepping and data alteration. For this purposes, Cloud DataPrep is the best option. For instance, if you want to get rid of null values or some ASCII characters which may cause errors in your ML model, you can use Cloud DataPrep.

**Cloud DataFlow, Cloud Dataproc**: Feature extraction, feature selection, scaling, dimension reduction also can be considered as a part of ML preprocessing. Since Cloud DataFlow and DataProc both support Spark, one can use Spark libraries for distributed fast preprocessing of the ML models input. Apache Spark MLlib can also be applied to many ML preprocessing/processing. Note that since  Cloud DataFlow supports Apache Beam, it is more into stream processing while Cloud DataProc is more Hadoop-based and is better for batch preprocessing. For more details, please refer to [Using Apache Spark with TensorFlow document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/11/using-apache-spark-with-tensorflow-on-google-cloud-platform)